# Getting attribute value in event handling code for JQuery / CC selector

Tags: jquery, css

I have a JQuery selector with some simple event handling attached.

```
jQuery('.ui-jqgrid-sdiv td[aria-describedby*="SUM"]').click(function(event) {alert('SUM=')});
```

Now, I want to find the exact value of the `aria-describedby` attribute. This could be say

```
SUM_1
SUM_2
SUM_3
SUM_4
```

Any tips how I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

By using [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) you can get it

try this

```
$('.ui-jqgrid-sdiv td[aria-describedby*="SUM"]').click(function(event){
   alert($(this).attr('aria-describedby'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

if you need that inside the click event then use `$(this)` and `.attr()`

try this

```
jQuery('.ui-jqgrid-sdiv td[aria-describedby*="SUM"]').click(function(event){
   alert($(this).attr('aria-describedby'));
});
```